# why we use [int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();] in sql asp.net

Tags: sql, asp.net, ado.net

int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: As we want to know the number of rows affected

Answer (score 1):

you can use it to get count of rows affected by your query (for example, if you wanna know, how many rows have been inserted in current transaction).
Please, read additional information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank u for your answer